# Algorithmic problem - quickly finding all #'s where value %x is some given value

Tags: algorithms

Problem I'm trying to solve, apologies in advance for the length:

Given a large number of stored records, each with a unique (String) field S. I'd like to be able to find through an indexed query all records where Hash(S) % N == K for any arbitrary N, K (e.g. given a million strings, find all strings where HashCode(s) % 17 = 5. Is there some way of memoizing this so that we can quickly answer any question of this form without doing the % on every value?

The motivation for this is a system of N distributed nodes, where each record has to be assigned to at least one node. The nodes are numbered 0 - (K-1) , and each node has to load up all of the records that match it's number:

If we have 3 nodes

- Node 0 loads all records where Hash % 3 ==0
- Node 1 loads all records where Hash % 3 ==1
- Node 2 loads all records where Hash % 3 ==2

adding a 4th node, obviously all the assignments have to be recomputed -

- Node 0 loads all records where Hash % 4 ==0
- ...
- etc

I'd like to easily find these records through an indexed query without having to compute the mod individually.

The best I've been able to come up with so far:

If we take the prime factors of N (p1 * p2 * ... )

if N % M == I then p % M == I % p for all of N's prime factors

e.g. 10 nodes :

N % 10 == 6 then

- N % 2 = 0 == 6 %2
- N % 5 = 1 == 6 %5

so storing an array of the "%" of N for the first "reasonable" number of primes for my data set should be helpful. For example in the above example we store the hash and the primes

*HASH*  *PRIMES (array of %2, %3, %5, %7, ... ])*

16    [0 1 1 2 .. ]

so looking for N%10 == 6 is equivalent to looking for all values where array[1]==1 and array[2] == 1.

However, this breaks at the first prime larger than the highest number I'm storing in the factor table. Is there a better way?

Comment: You may get a better luck on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com). You may need to re-phrase this a bit to bridge the gap between CS and Math.

Comment: Agreed - the fact that it's an "algorithm" doesn't necessarily mean CS skills :) This is highly mathematical in nature and I second @dasblinkenlight on migrating this to math.SE

Comment: presumably, you're doing this for load balancing of some sort.  How often are you re-balancing?  How often and how do the Strings change?  How often does your range of nodes change?  If your problem can accept some constraints (such as only allowing N nodes to range between X and Y) then some pragmatic solutions can be presented.  They won't necessarily be the mathematically pure solutions, but they will still work.

Comment: Have I misunderstood something, or did `N` change its meaning throughout your question? At first, it seemed to be the number of nodes, later, it seems to represent a hash code?

Comment: If you data is stored in RDBMS, then the operation you are trying to avoid is very cheap using a SQL SELECT (assuming HASH(s) is a column in your table)

Answer (score 3):

How important is it that formula be "Hash % num_machines"?  This formula is used for distributed caches, like memcached.  It works great until you add/remove nodes.  At that point, the advice is to abandon it and use [consistent hashing.](http://www.tomkleinpeter.com/2008/03/17/programmers-toolbox-part-3-consistent-hashing/)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion, although I didn't see an easy application of consistent hashing in this case. Suggestions for a better distribution than Hash % #machines (i.e. anything that's both fair and stable) would also be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood something, your conjecture is incorrect.

> If we take the prime factors of N (p1 * p2 * ... )
>
> if N % M == I then p % M == I % p for all of N's prime factors

How did you come up with that?

Let's say `N = 36` and `M = 6`

The prime factorization of `N = 2 * 2 * 3 * 3`. `36 % 6 = 0`

According to your statement, the following should hold:

```
p % 6 = 0 % p = 0
```

But clearly, this is not the case: `2 % 6 = 2 != 0`